# Video not working properly on an integrated Intel 82865G card

Tags: 11.04, intel-graphics

I hav a  fairly old computer... a P4 with hyper threading technology...1.5GB RAM, 64MB onboard graphics... I did a clean installing erasing the old 10.10.

The normal ubuntu mode says that the graphics isn't enough. In ubuntu classic mode, neither of the panels appear and when I take the mouse pointer in that area, it just appears for a moment and disappears.

In ubuntu classic no effects mode, it boots, but the panels are distorted and for the first time in my life, ubuntu HUNG... I'm a huge fan of ubuntu and its ability to work on almost any config but this really upset me... please help... is something wrong with my installation or is it a driver problem?

This is my video card:

> "00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82865G Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)"

its a Intel on board graphics controller

Comment: Please edit your question with the type of graphics card you have - `lspci | grep VGA`  Also, some people have found that installing `unity2d` from software centre fixes some graphical issues.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see [HERE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReinhardTartler/X/RevertingIntelDriverTo2.4) is, you can try reverting the driver to older version. Also classic desktop should work with 64MB IMHO, but is still really low memory and multimedia like flash and video might have problems.

Maybe there are some legacy intel drivers but in general old hardware is sometimes hard to make it work and is waste of your time because you won't gain much, so if you run out of options you can:

- buy old nvidia card for 10-15€ (I would check which works good, but most do)
- put it in and disable intel chip in bios
- install nvidia restricted drivers
- have fun with unity :P

regards and good luck!

Comment: +1 - That graphics chip really is quite underpowered. But I'm surprised it won't run the old GNOME 2 desktop. It's almost certainly a driver issue as you could run GNOME 2 DE in 10.10 and from a cursory inspection, nothing's really changed in 11.04 (if you're not booting into the *new* DE).

Comment: if its a driver issue, how can i rectify it?

Comment: I don't think there is any tool for configuretion on Intel as there is on Nvidia or Ati/Amd so asuming you have alot of time, it would require some poking around the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file, but be warned, make a copy of you're current one, because it's easy to break the configuration if you don't know what you are doing. Here is man page for xorg if you decide to poke around: http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/xorg.conf.5.html

Answer (score 1):

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82865G Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)

Is not supported in 11.04.

It's listed in Bugs:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/727594
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/774999

Two solutions I have found (but not test);

1)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then reboot the PC and retest.

2)

http://www.unixmen.com/linux-tutorials/linux-distributions/linux-distributions4-ubuntu/1540-top-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-1104-natty-narwhal

Answer (score 0):

Please see a solution here. Can fix the problem

http://sepirothemgnu.wordpress.com/2013/12/11/corregir-problemas-con-video-intel/

Comment: Please add the gist of the solution here.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.