# targeta grafica intel 8286g

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Video not working properly on an integrated Intel 82865G card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38144/video-not-working-properly-on-an-integrated-intel-82865g-card)

I need help knowing how to install and where to download my video card in it, intel 82865G 11.10 Ubuntu utilis grapics my pc is a dell optiplex GX270

ayuda necesito saber como instalar y de donde descargar mi tarjeta grafica en es; intel 82865g grapics utiliso Ubuntu 11.10 mi pc es una dell optiplex gx270

Comment: similar question here - the answers here probably still apply:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/38144/video-not-working-properly-on-an-integrated-intel-82865g-card

Answer (score -1):

Revisa este enlace http://intellinuxgraphics.org/download.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.