# Trouble installing ubuntu wubi 12.04 on windows xp dell dimension 3000

Tags: 12.04, installation, wubi, dell

I have previously installed ubuntu wubi 12.04 on my dell dimension 3000 with windows xp home. I succeeded, but I accidently made myself a standard user, not an admin. I uninstalled, then tried to reinstall, but it told me that it could not get the iso files, so i put the iso file in the same folder as wubi.exe.
When I ran the wubi then, it ran perfectly, but when i launched ubuntu it was "coping files", then it hung. The first time I installed it, I didn't have any trouble at all. Please help me.

Comment: What graphics card do you have? Make sure you are running the latest wubi.exe from here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/

Comment: I don't know what graphics card I have but I know I have wubi 12.04

Comment: @bcbc I found out that I have a Intel(R) 82865g Graphics Controller. Please tell me if you need any other information about my computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like this computer has issues with recent versions of Ubuntu e.g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38144/video-not-working-properly-on-an-integrated-intel-82865g-card) or [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1848339).

Now the first time you installed Wubi, it sounds like it used the *diskimage* install method (if you run `wubi.exe` standalone with no ISO). This does not use `ubiquity`. So if you want to try that, I'd suggest removing any Ubuntu ISOs first (i.e. Ubuntu DVDs, USBs, ISOs in the same folder as `wubi.exe` as well as ISOs on the root of any drive - because Wubi finds these).

Then make sure you have the latest 12.04 `wubi.exe` from here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ (because they get updated from time to time on an LTS release and the old ones won't work). That's the lightweight way to install with Wubi. It will still download the 500MB diskimage (if you're concerned about bandwidth).

But if you are okay with partitioning and don't need the Unity desktop, then skipping Wubi and using [lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) or [xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) will probably perform better on your hardware. For the longterm this is your best bet, because Wubi is being phased out and seems to get corrupted more easily due to running off a virtual disk.